# Value Error when trying to create a dictionary with lists as values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, valueerror

I am having issues creating a dictionary that assigns a list of multiple values to each key. Currently the data is in a list of list of 2 items:Category and Value, for example:

```
sample_data = [["January", 9],["Februrary", 10], ["June", 12], ["March", 15], ["January", 10],["June", 14], ["March", 16]]
```

It has to be transformed into a dicitonary like this:

```
d = {"January" : [9,10], "February":[10], "June":[12,14], "March": [15,16]}
```

This is my current code:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for category, value in sample_data:
    d[category].append(value)
```

This works for small samples but with very large samples of data it raises a ValueError saying too much values to unpack. Is there any way I could improve on this code or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: The error means one of the sub-list contains more than two values. You probably should clean your list first.

Comment: Is "Februrary" a typo in your input data?

Comment: @pise05 - try to see if the post can help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is prob. change the code to accept more than one `values`. This is just a *wild guess* - could it be something in your data (eg. value) problem - eg. one particular month has 2+ more data points showing *all at once.*

Note - ***value** means that it can take multiple values (more than one)

Without the * before value, it can **only take one** number at a time. That is why you got the error "Too many values to unpack..."

Because the sample data is not complete enough to show the exact error point, there's prob. other issue with data.  But it could help you eliminate the earlier "error"...or narrow down to it.

```
data = [["January", 9],["Februrary", 10], ["June", 12],
       ["March", 15], ["January", 10],["June", 14], ["March", 16],
       ['April', 20, 21, 22]]   # <--- add April & 3 values (to handle the earlier error)

from collections import defaultdict

# d = {"January" : [9,10], "February":[10], "June":[12,14], 
#     "March": [15,16]}
# This is my current code:

dc = defaultdict(list)
for category, *value in data:   # *value to accept multiple values
    dc[category].append(value)
    
print(dc)
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'January': [[9], [10]], 'Februrary': [[10]], 'June': [[12], [14]], 'March': [[15], [16]], 'April': [[20, 21, 22]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the `setdefault` method creates a list as the value for a key.

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for category, value in sample_data:
    d.setdefault(category, []).append(value)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'January': [9, 10], 'Februrary': [10], 'June': [12, 14], 'March': [15, 16]})
```

*Note: I do not have a larger sample set to work with but the setdefault() method could possibly help out with that.*